# How to pass the response of a sequence of HTTP requests to the initial client?

Tags: node.js, http

For an API I need to pass on data in a sequence of HTTP request, and the final response needs to be the response back to the initial client.

client > GET1 to node HTTP server > GET2 to URL2 > data2 = response.GET2 > POST3 to URL3, data2 is the payload > data3 = response.POST3 > response.GET1 = data3

I know how to make GET and POST request, and receive the responses with  `resp.on("data", chunk => {data += chunk;});` etc, but I can't seem figure out how to pass it back to the `res.write(data3);` of the initial client request.

I tried to put each 'next call' into each own function, and used return data, but the value is 'undefined'. I guess because the return is inside `resp.on("end", () => {return data});` or something.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fetch` in node now, so you can do:

```js
async function getFromURL2() {
    const response = await fetch('https://path.to/url2');
    return await response.json();
}

async function postToURL3(payload) {
    const response = await fetch("https://path.to/url3", {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(payload),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    });
    return await response.json();    
}

// assuming you are using express
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/api/endpoint', async (request, response) => {
    const firstResponse = await getFromURL2();
    const secondResponse = await postToURL3(firstResponse);
    response.json(secondResponse);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use the native `fetch()` API what can be used with `Promise`s. Then what you need is to chain the requests.

There are three ways to do it:

```
const response1 = await fetch(url1);
const response2 = await fetch(url2);
```

In this case you will need to add a top-level `try-catch` block, to use the `.catch(() => {})` extension on `fetch`.

The other way is to do nested calls:

```
return await fetch(url1).then((response1) => { return await fetch(url2) });
```

The third option would be the `allSettled()` or `all()` extensions.

```
const promises = [
 fetch(url1),
 fetch(url2)
];

// These will return an array what contains all the responses.
return await Promise.allSettled(promises);
// OR
return await Promise.all(promises);
```